# General form of Epanechnikov kernel

Tags: references, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing

[This Wikipedia source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanechnikov-Kern) states the Epanechnikov kernel to be of the form:

\begin{equation}
k_{n,d}=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{1}{2d} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right) \cdot \left(1 - \left(\frac{x}{d}\right)^{2n}\right) & ,|x| \leq d\\
  0 & ,|x| > d
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
I am not sure of the origins of this form, as all literature I am able to find only states the case of $n=1$ and $d=\sqrt{5}$. Can anybody point me to a paper, book or any over approved source that states the equation above?

Comment: Bernard Silverman's book on density estimation covers the Epanechnikov kernel and its properties.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I just had a look at this book in the library. The formulation of $K_e(t)$ it provides on page 42 is for the case of $d=\sqrt{5}$ and $n=1$ as mentioned above. I couldn't find the general form there.